# Can't add custom http header field to NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, post, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm trying to add a custom header field "jsonParams" to a POST request via addValue like so:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:120.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&error];


NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


[request addValue:jsonString forHTTPHeaderField:@"jsonParams"];

NSData *bodyData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:bodyData];
```

However the "jsonParams" field isn't getting added to the header fields. If I change the value from jsonString to a string object like @"test", though, it works just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: The line `NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` probably doesn't reflect what you want. Take a look at this string using the debugger or printing it out using `NSLog("jsonString : %@, jsonString);`

Comment: You’ve pretty printed it, which puts line breaks in the string. You can’t have a multi line header like that. But the whole idea of putting the JSON in a header is a bad (if not plain wrong) idea. Send the JSON in the body of the request, not a header. Right now you appear to be trying to put in both the body and a header.

Comment: @Rob That was it exactly. Putting the JSON in the header is a nasty workaround that I'm having to do, due to some environmental factors unfortunately

Comment: Well, if you avoid the pretty print option, you might get away with it. If worst comes to worst, you could percent escape it (which you'd have to unescape at the other end). It's too bad you can't fix the server, because this is just wrong. (But I guess you know that. Sometimes we're at the mercy of poorly written server code.)